# Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.WebData' Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-assembly

I am getting an exception message on the server hosting my ASP.NET MVC4 application. The application runs fine but when you make certain request that use types contained in certain third-party assemblies, I get the "**Could not load file or assembly...**" error message. 
The most nagging of which is the

> Could not load file or assembly 'WebMatrix.WebData' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

which prevents emails sent from my app from displaying the containing images (the images are sourced from a folder outside the document root projected via a virtual directory).

Under references, I have made sure that the **Copy To Local** property of the assembly is set to true. I am almost at my wits end.

**UPDATE**
I have noticed third party assemblies that are shipped in the bin folder all report the same error even though they exist there.

Thanks

Comment: Check your web.config to see if there are any modifications to that assembly. Check that the assembly is compatiable with what asp.net version your running (the same is highly reccomended). Consider using JustDecompile to further debug. Where

Comment: Checked all and everything seems to be in order. However, I have noticed third party assemblies that are shipped in the bin folder all report the same error even though they exist there. The ones contained in the GAC don't seem to throw this kind of exception.

Comment: Do these third party assemblies require license keys? I have had this error before and it was due to my assembly being asp.net 1.1 and I was using 4.5